# Change the Tint Color of UITableView Multiple Selection Check Circles

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uiview

When you enable `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` on a `UITableView` and then enter edit mode on it, each row will display a light grey circle on the left hand side. Upon tapping a row, the circle will be replaced with a tick icon, of the tint colour currently set to the table view.

[image: Selected and Deselected check circles in UITableView]

I'm wondering, is there any way to override the tint colours of both of these icons and control them manually? I've discovered if you set `cell.tintColor`, you can override the tint colour of the icon when it's checked (But not the hollow circle graphic), but I'd rather be able to change the tint colour of just this icon.

I'm getting the sinking feeling the only way to do this is to manually hack the internal subviews, but I'm hoping someone may have found a way I've missed.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `tintColor` property of the cell should be enough.

e.g.
`cell.tintColor = .green`

Comment: Yeah I mentioned I tried that in the question. ;) The problem is that will change the tint color of everything. Including the other tinted content in the cell.

Comment: My fault. Then indeed you need some subview hackery or add these checkmarks views manually and implement a selection flow manually, too. I just tried the same and when you enable allowsMultipleSelection the cell will automatically draw the circles and I have found no way to prevent this. Thus you cannot use the tableview's own selection flow.